# Grease pencil showing the wrong colour

Tags: grease-pencil, 2d

I've selected a colour that I wanted to choose.

[image]

Despite that, the line appeared to be grey rather than the green that I intended to pick when the line was drawn.

[image]

The strangest part about this is that I don't get this problem when I create a new blender file.

Answer (score 5):

It turned out that I was using the *Solid* shading instead of the **Material Preview** viewport shading.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to *Render Properties*, the icon with the camera, where you modify Ambient Occlusion, Depth of field and all that

Scroll all the way to the bottom to *Color Management*, under *View Transfom* change it from *Filmic* to *Standard*

My guess it's some sort of post-process LUT-like pass Blender has, that may be ok for movies, but for drawing like anime it robs the image of its color and brightness.

Comment: THANK YOU! I've been trying to solve this slightly-off-color in the viewport for the last hour. Other tweaks: `Viewport Shading: "Material Preview"` + `Viewport Shading dropdown -> Lighting -> Scene World off`